# How can I prove reflexive closure preserves symmetry, anti-symmetry, and transitivity?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Let R be a relation in A. Let R' be the reflexive closure of R. IE in the graph of R, each possible self loop is completed, yielding R'. How can I prove that this operation on the graph will preserve all three properties above in all cases? Is there a way of doing this in a graph? Would a prose explanation suffice, as in by definitions? Furthermore how would I do the same for a symmetric closure on a reflexive relation?

Comment: It depends on your 'audience' as to how formal this proof should be, but I think a proof by contradiction would make for a very readable proof for all properties, e.g. assume that $R$ is symmetric, but its reflexive closure is not, and derive a contradiction.

Comment: You just need to separate the definitions into the cases in which two of the variables are the same and those in which they are all different. When they are not different verifying the property reduces to verifying them on the original graph, since all those edges were already there, and the closure doesn't remove edges. The cases in which two of the variables are the same you check directly. For example ...

Comment: Symmetry: $xRy\implies yRx$. The case $x\neq y$ is true because it was true in the original graph and whether the edges $(x,y)$ and $(y,x)$ existed or not was up to the original graph. If $x=y$. Then $xRx$ is and edge of the new graph (it could have been already in the old too). Then $xRx\implies xRx$.

Comment: Anti-symmetry: $xRy\wedge yRx\implies x=y$. The case $x\neq y$ is true as before. The case $x=y$ is trivially true since the thesis of the implication is true.

Comment: Transitivity: $xRy\wedge yRz \implies xRz$. The case $x,y,z$ different from each other is true because it was true in the original graph. The case $x=y\neq z$: The condition is that $xRx\wedge xRz\implies xRz$, which is true by conjunction elimination. Similarly do the case $x\neq y=z$.